# JavaScript on server: to run or not to run (and why)

Tags: javascript

I was just wondering why would you run JavaScript in the client's browser rather then run it on a server (like you would PHP) - not sure if I'm making sense. What makes the browser a better place to run JS as opposed to the server?
Cheers!

Comment: It's designed for manipulating the clients experience of the web page. Having it take place client side massively reduces server load.

Comment: This question is probably overly broad.  You need to narrow the scope of your question to make it answerable.

Answer (score 3):

Running code in the browser allows changes to be made without having to do a (time consuming) round trip to the server that reloads the entire page.

It also shares the demand for CPU cycles across the clients instead of focusing it on a central server.

Comment: Man, that was quick answer! I thought I would check for answers in an hour or so, but this...

Comment: And possibly most importantly, it allows a page to exhibit dynamic behavior, something impossible with server-produced pure-HTML.

Comment: @Kirk Woll — Indeed: "without having to … reload the entire page"

Comment: @Quentin, there are many behaviors that cannot be simulated by "reloading the page".  For example, animations.  (or autocomplete as you type, or text-box validation as you type, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to reload a page for every change that occurs you need *some* language that is executed in the browser. That language just happens to be JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't as much of a problem as it used to be, what with super-fast internet connections, but the original reason that javascript was invented was that whenever a web page needed to respond to something the user did. If it took 100ms to make the one-way journey to the server, then that would come to a noticeable 2ooms delay everytime the user clicked on something. Load gmail and click on a message - the message appears almost instantaneously. For comparison, load gmail's plain html and see the difference when you click on a message - it takes much longer to load.